# Why the first post review tab is red?

Tags: support, review, top-bar

This happened to me on the ELU stack exchange, though I figure perhaps this could happen on the other sites.

The review tab has a red dot on the left of the first post review tab, however it's usually grey. I clicked to review the first posts, however nothing seemed to be out of the ordinary.

What does the red dot mean?

This is a screenshot of what happened.

[image: This is the red dot]

Comment: It means the number of total number of available review tasks for all users in that queue is above a certain threshold.

Comment: Heh, now that you've closed it as a duplicate I can edit the originals myself. Forgot about that.

Comment: The thing about my duplicate questions is that I don't know names for them so I can't necessarily find the duplicates.

Comment: I agree that the intended answer is buried deep down the [search results](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22red+dot%22), so I've upvoted your question.